# What is the difference between @Bean and @Component in Spring when using @Conditional?

Tags: java, spring

I want to register a Boss when there is a Car in Spring container.

My code is below

```java
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(value ={"org.example.springframework.condition","org.example.springframework.bean"})
public class ConditionConfig {
}

@Component
public class Car {
}

@Conditional(value = BossCondition.class)
@Component
public class Boss {
}

public class BossCondition implements Condition {

    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        return context.getRegistry().containsBeanDefinition("car");
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work, I can't discover the car in Condition.

Then, I change my code below, it can work well.

```java
@Configuration
public class ConditionConfig {
    @Bean
    public Car car() {
        return new Car();
    }

    @Bean
    @Conditional(value = BossCondition.class)
    public Boss boss() {
        return new Boss();
    }

}


public class Car {
}


public class Boss {
}

public class BossCondition implements Condition {

    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        return context.getRegistry().containsBeanDefinition("car");
    }
}
```

So, what is the difference between @Bean and @Component?